# Cannot uninstall MySQL server 8.0.13 using MySQL Installer or control panel

Tags: mysql

I was trying to study ASP.NET MVC and EntityFramework on my PC and for this, I needed to upgrade all MySQL modules version. I did, and it was going well. But when I tried to configure MySQL Server I didn't have luck, then some problems later, I decided to uninstall it.

I began this uninstall process first by the MySQL Installer Comunity remove option, but it returns me an error that I will show below, by the control panel, by command line on the website that I found in my search, even removing all trace of MySQL files in Program Files x86 and normal and ProgramData folders.

I tried all of these ways and, after the restart of the system and go to control panel or MySQL Installer Comunity, keeps showing me the MySQL Server still installed. It's my first time facing this problem and I really need help.

Attaching the log from MySQL Installer:

```
Beginning removal of MySQL Server 8.0.13.
1: Action 02:40:05: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {5A1AC698-82B9-4962-9FF5-EABADBA5A124} 
1: Action 02:40:05: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 02:40:05: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 02:40:05: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
1: Action 02:40:05: ValidateProductID. 
1: Action 02:40:05: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 02:40:05: FileCost. Computing space requirements
1: Action 02:40:05: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 02:40:07: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
1: Action 02:40:07: InstallValidate. Validating install
1: Action 02:40:09: InstallInitialize. 
1: Action 02:40:09: GenerateScript. Generating script operations for action:
1: InstallInitialize
1: Action 02:40:09: QtRemoveService. 
1: 
1: Action 02:40:09: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
1: Action 02:40:09: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: Action 02:40:10: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
1: Feature: Unpublishing Product Features
1: Action 02:40:10: SchedSecureObjectsRollback. 
1: Action 02:40:11: ExecSecureObjectsRollback. 
1: 
1: Action 02:40:11: ExecSecureObjectsRollback. 
1: 
1: Action 02:40:11: ExecSecureObjectsRollback. 
1: 
1: Action 02:40:12: ExecSecureObjectsRollback. 
1: 
1: Action 02:40:12: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
1: Key: Removing system registry values, Name: 
1: Action 02:40:12: RemoveShortcuts. Removing shortcuts
1: Shortcut: Removing shortcuts
1: Action 02:40:12: RemoveFiles. Removing files
1: File: Removing files, Directory: 
1: Action 02:40:12: RemoveFolders. Removing folders
1: Folder: Removing folders
1: Action 02:40:12: CreateFolders. Creating folders
1: Action 02:40:12: InstallFiles. Copying new files
1: Action 02:40:12: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Action 02:40:12: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Action 02:40:12: InstallServices. Installing new services
1: Action 02:40:12: RegisterUser. Registering user
1: Action 02:40:12: RegisterProduct. Registering product
1: Action 02:40:12: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
1: Action 02:40:12: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
1: Action 02:40:12: InstallFinalize. 
1: Action 02:40:15: InstallInitialize. 
1: Action 02:40:16: QtRemoveService. 
1: Action 02:40:18: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: QtRemoveService
1: InstallInitialize
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {5A1AC698-82B9-4962-9FF5-EABADBA5A124} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Remove' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.13' failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error when uninstalling 5.6 after installing 8.0.17, no idea how to solve it